# Applying IEnumerable<'T>.OrderBy on a IQueryable<'T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression, ienumerable

I've got a custom type which I use on my repositories that helps me explicitly represent query options, e.g. for sorting, paging etc.

Initially, the interface looked like this:

```
public class IQueryAction<TEntity> {
    IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyTo(IQueryable<T> entitity);
}
```

With that I can represent sorting like this:

```
public class SortingAction<TEntity, TSortKey> : IQueryAction<TEntity>
{
    public Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> SortAction { get; }

    public SortingAction(Expression<Func<TEntity, TSortKey>> sortExpression) {
        SortAction = q => q.OrderBy(sortExpression);
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyTo(IQueryable<TEntity> query) {
        return SortAction(query);
    }

}
```

Most of the time I work with Entity Framework, so this is not a problem. However now I need to implement the `IQueryAction<'T>` model for a data source which doesn't provide a query provider (`IQueryProvider`). I could now refactor my interface to use `IEnumerable<'T>` instead of `IQueryable<'T>` and expect a `Func` *delegate* for the key selector instead of a *lambda expression*.

Now my question is: Would this cause the sort action to be run in memory instead of on the query provider when an `IQueryable<'T>` is simply being casted to an `IEnumerable<'T>`? Since I wouldn't pass an *expression* anymore, but rather a *delegate*, how could the query provider still know what *key* I'd like to use for the query? And if that won't work anymore: What could I do to fit both, sorting in memory and on the query provider, depending on the underlying type of `IEnumerable<'T>`?

### Usage example

```
public class MyEntity {
    public int    Id   { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set }
}

// somewhere in code
var orderByName = new SortingAction<MyEntity, string>(x => x.Name);
myEntityRepository.GetAll(orderByName);

// ef repository impl
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(IQueryAction<TEntity> queryAction) {
    return queryAction.ApplyTo(dbContext.Set<TEntity>()); // runs on the query provider
}

// misc repository impl not supporting IQueryable/IQueryProvider
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(IQueryAction<TEntity> queryAction) {
    var result = someProvider.Sql("SELECT *")...
    return queryAction.ApplyTo(result);
}
```

Comment: Yes it will cause the sorting to happen in memory if you use the `IEnumerable<T>` methods. You can convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to an `IQueryable<T>` using `AsQueryable` and use the expression tree methods instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could I do to fit both, sorting in memory and on the query
>   provider

Leave `IQueryAction<TEntity>` as is, and convert `IEnumerable<T>` to `IQueryable<T>`, using [`AsQueryable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb507003%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension:

```
var list = new List<YourEntity> { /* ... */ };
var queryableList = list.AsQueryable();

sortingAction.ApplyTo(queryableList);
```

Ultimately this will do in-memory sorting for in-memory sequences (like collections), and it will send queries against databases for "true" queryables.

Comment: Seems like that's the only option. I wanted to change/avoid that because with that option, I'd inevitably leak IQueryable<'T> into my repositories (like I already do with my existing interface) that would tell the client 'hey, my service supports a queryprovider!' even if that isn't really the case sometimes. Oh well. :/

Comment: Actually, the problem is deeper, than you think about it. There is an opinion, that `IQueryable` in public interfaces is evil, because `IQueryable` doesn't guarantee, that the applied method won't throw an exception at run-time. E.g., EF has a limitation about types, which could be used in queries, while in-memory provider - doesn't. From architectural point, `IQueryable`-based repositories must be avoided, and repository must provide methods with predefined sorting, ordering, projection, etc. But IRL it leads to another kind of problems (repository code grows very fast).

Comment: Yes, I know. I always try to avoid god-like interfaces, but definitely not at all cost. For e.g. an advanced reporting application, I just try to secure the APIs enough so that clients can't execute something not possible on my storage provider. But implementing every combination and filter and query just to have like 99% of IQueryable<'T> in the end is just not worth the pain. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Would this cause the sort action to be run in memory instead of on the query provider when an IQueryable<'T> is simply being casted to an IEnumerable<'T>?

Yes, because you will be binding to the `Enumerable` extension methods which do sorting in-memory.  It doesn't matter at that point what the underlying provider is; the `Enumerable` extension methods will enumerate the underlying collection and "sort" it in-memory.

> What could I do to fit both, sorting in memory and on the query provider, depending on the underlying type of `IEnumerable<T>`?

The client can call `ToQueryable()` before calling the methods.  If the underlying collection is *already* an `IQueryable<T>` then the input is just cast; otherwise an adapter is placed on top of the `IEnumerable` to adapt the `IQueryable` methods to `IEnumerable` methods

Comment: Is there a way to get around? Since the `.OrderBy()` implementation of `IQueryable<'T>` expects a lambda expression as key selector, it doesn't seem that LINQ is really interoperable here. :/

Comment: Well, `Queryable` expects an _expression_ instead of a _delegate_.    The compiler can (and will) compile a lambda into either depending on the use case. You can easily convert from one to the other.  Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to do - can you add a non-working example of how you'd _like_ it to work?

Comment: Provided usage example. Aas you can see, I can't use my existing interface because the result set from the data source that doesn't support `IQueryable<'T>` is a simple list (and thus not implementing `IQueryable<'T>`). And no, I can't easily convert from a *delegate* to an *expression*.. well, I can, but then my expression just wraps a delegate and query providers usually don't know wtf this is. :)